# MySQL Database schema design and relationships

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm designing a project, where logged **users** can add **rating** to any of the **books** they read, and also add **status** to any book they *want to read/read/will read*. 
So i created tables: Book, User, Rating, Status and I'm not sure how to connect all of these informations in one table (and if it's possible).

Right now, I have **user_books** table where I store foreign keys to *status_id*, *rating_id*, *book_id* and *user_id*, but I'm not sure if it is a right way to do this.

Relationships that I want to create in my SpringBoot application:

- User-Book *ManyToMany*,
- Book-Rating *ManyToOne*,
- Book-Status *ManyToOne*.

[image]

Comment: Hi Tyler, I think your schema is fine. Only thing I would think about is separating user rating and user status from table user_books_table in different tables to remain flexible

Comment: By that I understand, that you recommend to create table f.e. User_book_details with user_rating and user_status, but, how would you connect that table and with which table? Users or User_Book?

Comment: I just drew all that schema and I think that no matter what user and book has to be in the same table, because no matter if it's rating or status, both of them have to connected in some way so that User-> can -> Rate/Change Status -> of a Book.

Answer (score 0):

looks you want to create a many-to-many relationship. Logically many-to-many relationships do exists, but when it comes to Physical model, you create a mapping table, which you already did it -> user_books table. Based on the id from the mapping table, you can get these 
    1) Number of users read "that" book.
    2) Highest ratings on a book.
    3) Ratings based on a book on a user age group (if the user table has age)